# unexpected costs when using Elastic Pools

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

Can someone explain how sql databases are costed in azure when using an elastic pool. The Elastic Pools' service tear is "General Purpose (Most Budget friendly, serverless compute)", the hardware is set to Standard-series (Gen5).  We have set the max vcores to 4 and the Data max size to 500gb.  According to the estimated cost this should be around $606.75 per month however over the month of may we were charged by our third party retailer over $2200.  I dont understand why there is such a difference Do we get charged for consumption ontop of the base fee?

Answer (score 0):

With elastic pools you are billed for each hour a pool exists at the highest eDTU or vCores, regardless of usage or whether the pool was active for less than an hour. The cost of an elastic pool depends on the number of databases and the performance level of the pool. To get a more realistic estimation than the Azure Elastic Pool pricing calculator, try to scale the number of cores of the pool and there you will see a more realistic pricing considering the number and size of databases on the pool. See the estimated price on the image.

[image]

As you can see on the image there are added costs for storage. The price of storage for an elastic pool is the max data size specified, multiplied by the storage unit price of the service tier.

Every time you scale up the number of cores on the pool the consumption per hour increases. I had a customer that manually increased the number of vcores at 1 pm each day to 32 vcores at a cost of USD$8.00 per hour to deal with increased demand and bad T-SQL programming, at the end of the month he was paying USD$2,000 - $2,500. Maybe that is happening on your scenario.